# forecast(auto.arima): match.fun(FUN) : node stack overflow

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

After spending time in reading and implementing solutions, I am still not able to pinpoint the reasons of the below **error message**, and hope to get some feedback.

- Author's Source code: [kukuruku.co](http://kukuruku.co/hub/r/oil-series-oil-prices-in-r) (*Stationarity Tests could be skipped*)

My concern is about:

```
fcast.arima <- forecast(fit.arima, h, lambda=L) -> Error in match.fun(FUN) : node stack overflow
```

Unless there is a **bug** in **R**, I can't see where this *error* might come from, to be honest, to the extent that `fit.arima` produces some output, `h` && `L` are all fine. Documentation from `forecast{}` package allows the syntax `forecast(object,h,lambda)`, thus there is strictly nothing theoretically wrong with it. Eventually all the required `libraries` have been loaded.

What strikes me the most:

```
fcast.nn <- forecast(fit.nn, h, lambda=L)
```

does work, so definitely something bizzare is happening with **R** *ARIMA*

Best,

Here is the *cleansed code*:

```
library(Quandl)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

oil.ts <- Quandl("DOE/RBRTE", trim_start="1987-11-10", trim_end="2015-01-01", type="zoo")
oil.tsw <-Quandl("DOE/RBRTE", trim_start="1987-11-10", trim_end="2015-01-01", type="zoo", collapse="weekly")
oil.tsm <-Quandl("DOE/RBRTE", trim_start="1987-11-10", trim_end="2015-01-01", type="ts", collapse="monthly")
plot(oil.tsm, xlab="Year", ylab="Price, $", type="l")
lines(lowess(oil.tsm), col="red", lty="dashed")

L <- BoxCox.lambda(ts(oil.ts, frequency=260), method="loglik")
Lw <- BoxCox.lambda(ts(oil.tsw, frequency=52), method="loglik")
Lm <- BoxCox.lambda(oil.tsm, method="loglik")

# Fit NN for long-run
fit.nn <- nnetar(ts(oil.ts, frequency=260), lambda=L, size=3)
fcast.nn <- forecast(fit.nn, h=520, lambda=L)
fit.nnw <- nnetar(ts(oil.tsw, frequency=52), lambda=Lw, size=3)
fcast.nnw <- forecast(fit.nnw, h=104, lambda=Lw)
fit.nnm <- nnetar(oil.tsm, lambda=Lm, size=3)
fcast.nnm <- forecast(fit.nnm, h=24, lambda=Lm)
par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
plot(fcast.nn, include=1040)
plot(fcast.nnw, include=208)
plot(fcast.nnm, include=48)

# Fit ARIMA, NN and ETS for short-run
short <- ts(oil.ts[index(oil.ts) > "2014-06-30" & index(oil.ts) < "2014-12-  01"], frequency=20)
short.test <- as.numeric(oil.ts[index(oil.ts) >= "2014-12-01",])
h <- length(short.test)
fit.arima <- auto.arima(short, lambda=L)
fcast.arima <- forecast(fit.arima, h, lambda=L)
fit.nn <- nnetar(short, size=7, lambda=L)
fcast.nn <- forecast(fit.nn, h, lambda=L)
fit.tbats <-tbats(short, lambda=L)
fcast.tbats <- forecast(fit.tbats, h, lambda=L)
par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
plot(fcast.arima, include=3*h)
plot(fcast.nn, include=3*h)
plot(fcast.tbats, include=3*h)
```

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example?

Comment: @DatamineR: sure. same link as mentioned in the thread [http://kukuruku.co/hub/r/oil-series-oil-prices-in-r]

Comment: @DatamineR: Thread edited too, in case it helps.

Comment: `fcast.arima` workst for me without any erros

Comment: @DatamineR: lucky... and in the same time glad to read it as it purely evidences something is going wrong with my pc and not in the code. as mentioned i could not see anything wrong with the syntaxes

Comment: Try googling `node stack overflow`. There are some posts about it

Comment: @DatamineR: 've done it since ages...  I might take some time but will figure out. I just need to know that `stricto sensu`  the code as it is edited works on someone's else pc.

Comment: @FYI: I had to delete `forecast{}` from `lib folder` and re-install to make `forecast(arima.object...)` or `forecast.Arima(object..)` work. Even simple examples illustrated in`?forecast.Arima` were producing same `error` for some reason. :) problem solved, but sa

Comment: @DatamineR... dly I have not found the real source of the bug.